# How to localize Range attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, range, custom-data-attribute

So I need to localize this

```
 [Range(1, 150, ErrorMessage = "")]
```

I tried to use

```
[Range(1, 150, ErrorMessage = MyApp.Properties.Resource.ErrorMessageMustBeBetween)]
```

where `MyApp.Properties.Resource.ErrorMessageMustBeBetween` is

```
"{0} must be between {1} and {2}."
```

and it says

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type

How it could be done then? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName` to use a resource for a Data Annotation.

Try:

```
[Range(1, 150, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyApp.Properties.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageMustBeBetween")]
```

Comment: Your solution is working but it should be `ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageMustBeBetween")]` Anyway I will mark it like an answer. And thank you!